# Get video title from video ID?

Tags: delphi, youtube-api, delphi-xe2

If I only have the 11-character Youtube VIDEO_ID, how can I get the TITLE of this video?
If there was an example on how to do this in Delphi it would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call with id.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=JNEJPffln1k&fields=items%2Fsnippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```